# I dont understand this output using selenium chromedriver (python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with the selenium chrome webdriver in python, but it doesn't work and it crashed any time I run the code. This is the output, and I sincerally don't know what to do.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58441/devtools/browser/a6122e07-0d3e-49ea-9308-d5c4dc4461ab
[19592:21540:0929/222340.633:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.664:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.671:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.686:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.693:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.695:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.698:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:23:40.698] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. (0x2)
[19592:21540:0929/222340.698:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.700:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:23:40.700] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
[19592:21540:0929/222340.705:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.712:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[19592:21540:0929/222340.712:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(441)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

After that, it just shows a crash message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marti\OneDrive\Escritorio\woo\DiscordBot\BetterCollege\tester.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
  File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00EB1ED3+2236115]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E492F1+1807089]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D566FD+812797]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D758F9+940281]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D719C9+924105]
        Ordinal0 [0x00DA806C+1146988]
        Ordinal0 [0x00DA7A6A+1145450]
        Ordinal0 [0x00DA18A6+1120422]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D7A73D+960317]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D7B71F+964383]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0115E7E2+2743074]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011508D4+2685972]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F42BAA+532202]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F41990+527568]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E5080C+1837068]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E54CD8+1854680]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E54DC5+1854917]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E5ED64+1895780]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x768F6739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77658FD2+1218]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77658F9D+1165]
```

Can someone help me? :c

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting a chrome driver that is your around your chrome version from here:
[Chrome Driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
Then put it in the path of the folder and check out the following code:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way but it is boring, because every time the new version of driver released, you should go and repeat all steps again and again.

You should download binary chromedriver, unzip it somewhere in you PC and set path to this driver like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/user/drivers/chromedriver')
```

But with webdriver manager, you just need to do two simple steps:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

And use it with Chrome

```
# selenium 3
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: Hi, i've recently installed a binary chromedriver for the version 106 of chrome (which is the one I have). I added it to the same path as my python script (which I changed to your suggestion) to avoid problems, but it still showing the same. I've tried installing an older version of chrome and chromedriver, doesn't work :c